# Make javascript Alert/Confirm dialogs more visible (especially in the Google Chrome browser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, alert

In recent versions of the Google Chrome browser, javascript Alert dialogs, and Confirm dialogs, are not very visible. They don't make a sound when appearing, they're positioned near the top of the screen, and they're white so they blend in too easily with most websites.

This causes users to not realize the Alert is there, and since the Alert freezes the browser until dismissed, users can easily think their browser is frozen.

What are some ways to make the javascript Alert stand out more?

Comment: Don't use alerts.  Google may be making them stand out less in Chrome because they are annoying.

Comment: There are better options than alert and confirm. better to look to see why you are using them and integrate errors and other messages in a better manner.

Comment: I'll have to consider that. Currently, I believe there are valid reasons for using Confirm dialogs. For instance, a Confirm dialog just popped up on JSFiddle, asking if I really wanted to navigate away without saving the changes.

Comment: showModalDialog() can behave like confirm or alert and lets you display a whole custom HTML file instead of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create your own Alert, using div overlays. However, doing that for Confirm dialogs would be more difficult, since you often want all execution to stop until the user chooses OK or Cancel on the Confirm dialog.

A great option is the following, which allows you to continue using the browser's Alert and Confirm dialogs:

Create these functions (uses Jquery but can be modified to Javascript):

```
function alrt(msg) {
    var tint = $('<div class="PopupBgTint"></div>');
    tint.appendTo('body');
    alert(msg);
    tint.remove();
}
function cnfrm(msg) {
    var tint = $('<div class="PopupBgTint"></div>');
    tint.appendTo('body');
    var rtrn = confirm(msg);
    tint.remove();
    return rtrn;
}
```

In your CSS file, define PopupBgTint like so:

```
.PopupBgTint
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index:99999;
}
```

Then, instead of calling
`alert('Hello World')` or `confirm('Continue?')`
instead call `alrt('Hello World')` or `cnfrm('Continue?')`

That's all there is to it. This will create a temporary tinted overlay covering your entire page, with the Alert/Confirm dialog on top of it, making the dialog MUCH more visible.

See example at:
http://jsfiddle.net/wcU3f/1/
(jsfiddle uses frames though, which negates part of the effect, but you get the idea how it'd function on a full webpage.)

Comment: You could alternatively override the existing functions so that no code needs changing.

Comment: Great point Archer. If you want to override all your alerts with this code, you could definitely do that.

Comment: I took over an old project that had `parseInt(n)` all over the place, without a radix value.  I fixed that by overriding the `parseInt` function to assume 10 if you didn't pass one, fixing a LOT of problems in the process.  I'm a big fan of overriding, without going too far with it.

Comment: Scratch the idea of overriding Alert or Confirm. To override, you need to use `apply`, but that's not supported in IE8 and below. So it appears my original code is the way to go.